# Dynamic routing with an ingress controller

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod

Is it possible to do a dynamic routing with a nginx ingress controller? By dynamic I mean based on the url I need to strip and fetch a value from the url and route based on that value. Let me know how if it’s possible. If it’s not possible with nginx controller , let me know any other way in which this is possible. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly. Would something like [Nginx Ingress Rewrite](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/) work for you? Could you provide use scenario?

Comment: When user logs in, I create a pod and a service for him, and I need to route him to his specific service whenever he sends a request. So , in simple words , I need to extract the name of the user from the path and route him to a service set up for him.

Comment: Have you check K8s dosc regarding [Dynamic Ingress in Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/06/07/dynamic-ingress-in-kubernetes/) ?

Comment: Hi @Kowshhal do you find a solution about your question? I have a similar problem to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Ingress controllers are based on `Ingress` objects. Kubernetes objects definitions are static by nature (so we could version control them).

From what I gathered in the comments, when a user requests `domain.com/foo` they will be redirected to their instance of your app ? You will need a source to get the updated info.

I could see 2 ways of doing that:

- Edit the ingress object manually or programmatically (using helm or some other templating software)
- Make a dedicated app using a persistent database and trigger redirections from there: `domain.com/*` -> `redirect app` -> `user app. This way you can control your users list as you want.

It depends if the end user will stay on `domain.com/user` or if they get redirected to another unique domain. I would need more info to discuss that.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking of having a redirection app setup, because I can’t change ingress rules because that same ingress is being used by other apps as well, So I guess it’s logical to create a redirection app below the ingress.

Answer (score 0):

Attach tags to your services and let Traefik do the rest!

https://docs.traefik.io/routing/providers/consul-catalog/

I guess this could be very close to what you want to acheeve.

Best of luck!

Comment: Path /foo is not exactly foo, In fact it’s unknown, it changes dynamically, based on that I need to redirect to a service specially created for that route, and the rules are determined during run time.

Comment: Inorder to be precise, each user has his own service and I need to route him to his service based on the url which has his name.

Comment: To be more clear, I need to extract the name of the user from the path and route him to a service set up for him. Is this possible?

Comment: How do you deploy one service for each user?

Comment: I edited my answer based on your explanation. That could do the trick :)

Comment: I have a java code which creates pods and services for me. That’s how I create a service whenever a user logs in.

Comment: Thanks I’ll check it. So nginx doesn’t have that feature?

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic routing with Ambassador Header-based Routing

Ambassador is another Envoy-based solution. It has free and commercial versions. Ambassador is described as a «Kubernetes-native API gateway for microservices» and it brings corresponding benefits — such as the tight integration with the primitives of K8s. Having a pack of features you’d expect from an Ingress controller, it can also be used with a variety of service mesh solutions (Consul, Linkerd, Istio).

The headers Annotation
The headers attribute is a dictionary of header: value pairs. Ambassador Edge Stack will only allow requests that match the specified header: value pairs to reach the target service.

You can also set the value of a header to true to test for the existence of a header.

```
---
apiVersion: getambassador.io/v2
kind:  Mapping
metadata:
  name:  user-header-based-routing
spec:
  prefix: /backend/
  service: userA
  headers:
    x-authenticated-user: userA
...
```